First layer flow rate too low or global nozzle Z distance too large?
I had a problem with ASA part warping and not sticking to the build plate as shown by this question and answer
Issue stem from under extrusion of the first layer and was solved by bumping first layer flow rate from 100 % to 120 %.
I am wondering, how does one differentiate between first layer flow rate being too low or global Z nozzle distance from plate being too large for the whole print? I've seem comments that adjusting first layer flow is just a hack and it does not address the original problem - whatever that may be.
Before initial layer flow rate increased:

After initial layer flow rate increased to 120 %:


You asked for a "reputable source", but the question here is not one that calls for authority of any kind. It's a question of basic mathematics. If you want that explained I can potentially add it to my answer.

You cannot distinguish wrong flow from wrong Z offset in just the first layer. You need more layers to distinguish. Fortunately, it looks like you've already done that.
There is never a reason for the first layer flow to be any different from flow for the rest of the print. If you're finding that you need 120% flow on the first layer (assuming 100% everywhere else), this means that the distance between the nozzle and the bed when printing the first layer is 20% larger than it should be. For example, if your first layer thickness is 0.2 mm, this means your nozzle is actually about 0.24 mm from the bed, and the Z offset needs to be adjusted to lower the nozzle by 0.04 mm.
